# Check whether CMIS document can be modified by user

Tags: cmis, opencmis, dotcmis

I have some code that downloads a CMIS document:

```
contentStream = remoteDocument.getContentStream();
```

What is the most efficient way to check whether the current CMIS user has write access to this document's data content or not?

Preferably without making additional CMIS requests.

Comment: Can't you get it from the Allowable Actions on the document?

Comment: @Gagravarr: I am using that right now, but wondering whether there is anything better.

Answer (score 1):

AllowableActions.Actions has the information:

```
bool writeable = document.AllowableActions.Actions.Contains(
  PermissionMappingKeys.CanSetContentDocument)
```

If there is anything more efficient I would love to hear about it, though.